# How to create a CASE statement depending on the result of a Select Statement with parameter?

Tags: sql, case

Using SQL Server, How can I create a CASE statement depending on the value of a Select Statement with a parameter ?

I need to insert data if the ID doesn't exist (NULL) in table Products and if it exists I need to update the data.

I have the below CASE statement query but the syntax is wrong:

```
Select CASE WHEN (select ID from Products where ProdID = @ProdID) = NULL
then 
(INSERT INTO Table...)
Else
(Update Table...)
END as Prods
FROM Products
```

Comment: sql server or mysql ?

Comment: I think you're looking for the IF statement

Comment: Sounds like you should use a merge statement instead: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29 or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if you are using mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS( select ID from Products where ProdID = @ProdID )
BEGIN
   (Update Table...)
END

ELSE
 (INSERT INTO Table...)
```

For SQL Server 2008 + versions see [**MERGE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb510625.aspx) statement

Comment: Awesome, worked with IF EXISTS statement, Thanks a lot !